# Bootstrap navbar-toggle background color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

For a standard navbar-toggle, the hamburger shows up if the screen shrinks and works as expected.

What I want to do is this:

When the screen is small and the hamburger shows up, I want to change the background color of the items that display when the hamburger is clicked. I don't want to change the navbar-toggle itself, but rather the back color of the items that pop up when the toggle is clicked.

By default the background color inherits the navbar-collapse background color. I want to over-ride this when the hamburger is clicked.

Is this possible?

Comment: please post your `nav-bar` code

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom css class to the dropdown `<ul>` like this: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yL3defqf/)